# Why in this context use...( i are )not (i am ) and what does that mean

Tags: grammar

"A perfect misanthropist’s heaven: 
and Mr. Heathcliff and I are such a suitable pair to divide 
the desolation between us"(from Wuthering hights )

Answer (score 5):

Mr Heathcliff AND I = two people. So they are a suitable pair. 
It is a [compound subject](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/15-sentences-using-compound-subjects-and-compound-verbs.html)

Comment: Or perhaps more relevantly, ***we*** are a suitable pair. ;)